# After using every, should it be singular or plural?

Tags: grammar

Is it correct to use:
Not every student is as rude as you mentioned

Or

Not every student are as rude as you mentioned.

Thanks

Comment: Some of these might help: https://english.stackexchange.com/search?q=not+every+is+are

Comment: "Every" explicitly indicates a distributive interpretation of the predication property as reflected in the selection of a singular head, which of course has singular agreement.

Comment: Simpler version: "every" = "every **one**", so 'is'. You seem to know this implicitly since you use "every student" instead of "every (*)student**s**".

Answer (score 4):

The singular is correct in your example. "Not every student **is** as rude, as you mentioned.

> Every

> from Cambridge English Grammar Today [Link](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/grammar/british-grammar/every)

> Every is a determiner.

> Every meaning ‘each member of a group’

> We use every + singular noun to refer individually to all the members of a complete group of something:

> There’s a photograph on the wall of every child in the school.

> Try to answer every question.

> When "every" refers to the subject of the clause, we use a singular verb:

> > Every player wants to be in a winning team.

> > Not: Every player want ...

> Every cook needs good knives and a chopping board.

> The negative of every is normally not every:

BUT not every noun has a plural form.

> We use singular pronouns and possessives to refer back to every + noun, especially in more formal styles, and especially when what we refer to is not human:

> Every store has a manager in charge of it.

> Every area has its own park.

> In less formal styles, the pronoun or possessive may be plural:

> Every student gets a laptop. They have to give it back at the end of the course.

> Every user has his (or her) own password.

Comment: ELU is an advanced Q&A. Elementary questions are dealt with on [ell.se]

Comment: @Kris, should I not then have tried to answer the question but suggested the questioner go to ELL in a comment?

Comment: I would naturally think so.