# Correct Usage of Plural Possessive Word "user"?

Tags: grammatical-number, apostrophe

Which of the following is the correct usage of the plural possessive word "user"?

> We would like to store a cookie in every user's browser.

or

> We would like to store a cookie in every users' browser.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [After using every, should it be singular or plural?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/425289/after-using-every-should-it-be-singular-or-plural). And would you say 'We would like to store a cookie in the browser of every user' or 'We would like to store a cookie in the browser of every users'?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is in the word every. Every refers to individuals in a group. User is, then, to be preferred over users, and the first sentence is our winner: We would like to store a cookie in every user's browser.

Comment: Whether or not one uses possessive marker(s), nouns following each, every, either, neither are always singular.

Comment: Please include a reference to support and substantiate the answer. Else use "comment" if you have the privilege to post comments. Good Luck.

Comment: ... And please familiarise yourself with the site; a lot of questions have been answered in the past, agreement after 'every' might be expected to be (and certainly is) one such, and avoiding bloat is an important principle on ELU (bloat hinders researching an answer, and smacks of amateurism).